# My project, which uses a gradle dependency, stopped working when I restarted my computer

Tags: java, gradle

I am making a program that requires a Gradle dependency, and I am using eclipse. It was working yesterday, and I didn't change anything, but when I restarted my computer it stopped working. This is my first time using Gradle.

I tried refreshing Gradle and restarting eclipse, but it still doesn't see the dependency. I tried changing the distribution url of Gradle in the gradle-wrapper.properties file, and copying everything from one project to another but nothing has worked so far.

this is the content of my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url  "https://dl.bintray.com/emilybjoerk/lisoft" 
    }
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'


    // this is the dependency I am trying to get to work.
    compile 'org.li-soft.gonector:gonector:1.0.0'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is the error message:

> Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution
>   'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.1-bin.zip'. A
>   problem occurred configuring root project 'MyGoEngine'. Could not open
>   cp_proj remapped class cache for ass53uh6ku2mc5yoyd4qs6g8f
>   (C:\Users\Nikolas.gradle\caches\5.6.1\scripts-remapped\build_159eps3wjadzhd5aqrvmhdzni\ass53uh6ku2mc5yoyd4qs6g8f\cp_proje7ca86eb00f9d6cbee2b842ef043afcb).
>   Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file
>   'C:\Users\Nikolas\eclipse-workspace\MyGoEngine\build.gradle'
>   (C:\Users\Nikolas.gradle\caches\5.6.1\scripts\ass53uh6ku2mc5yoyd4qs6g8f\cp_proj\cp_proje7ca86eb00f9d6cbee2b842ef043afcb).
>   BUG! exception in phase 'conversion' in source unit '*BuildScript*'
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression

I deleted the contents of C:\Users\Nikolas.gradle\caches, and ran again. This was the console error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyGoEngine'.
>
>   > Could not open cp_proj remapped class cache for j3obw14yy0cihl9fkn41unq7
>   >     (C:\Users\Nikolas.gradle\caches\5.6.1\scripts-remapped\build_159eps3wjadzhd5aqrvmhdzni\j3obw14yy0cihl9fkn41unq7\cp_proje7ca86eb00f9d6cbee2b842ef043afcb).
>   >     Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Nikolas\eclipse-workspace\MyGoEngine\build.gradle'
>   >     (C:\Users\Nikolas.gradle\caches\5.6.1\scripts\j3obw14yy0cihl9fkn41unq7\cp_proj\cp_proje7ca86eb00f9d6cbee2b842ef043afcb).
>   >     BUG! exception in phase 'conversion' in source unit '*BuildScript*' org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be
>   >     cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 5s

Comment: Looks like you did an upgrade your `gradle` now you have two or more which are clashing ... removed the others

Comment: what should I do to fix that?

Comment: Remove all content in `C:\Users\Nikolas.gradle\caches` and run again.

Comment: I did that, It did not work, but now it gave a different error in console. Edited the post with the error message.

Comment: OK I see, before which `gradle version` were you using? did you do an update to `gradle`?

Comment: Remove all content in `.gradle` in order to can download again

Comment: I was using the default that eclipse supplied, 5.4.. When I started getting this error I tried switching the distribution url to that of 5.6.1, which did not fix it. I then tried your solutions, switched it back to 5.4 and tried them again. Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: I'm not on my home PC right now, but it seems like there is a .Gradle both within the project itself and in my user folder. I will try deleting both when I get home.

Comment: Okay, let me know if removing the ` gradle cache` works.

Comment: I deleted `.gradle` both within the project folder and my user folder. It is still not working

Comment: I decided to just clone the dependency straight from its github. It worked first try. Nothing with gradle was working.

Comment: Looks like you are working on `wrapper of gradle` which is `gradlew` well, if this worked on your environment, it would be great if you post your answer so that other people will be helpful :) , kind regards

Comment: I just stopped using Gradle. That solution probably isn't of much help to other people with the same problem.

Comment: Yeah, but I think the issue was because you had a dirty `gradle` since on the error says:  you have a `class cached` which it should be one of which you need it then I told you remove the cache, anyways I would try to reproduce the error if you provide me a basic example which displays this error,  :) if you want to feel you more confident so send me a mail